# Exchange: Forward copy of all received emails to another internal server

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2010, mail-forwarding

We need send all emails coming into exchange into another server, which will process them for metadata, while also delivering the email to the internal mailboxes. Does anyone know how to accomplish this duplication/forwarding of emails.

At the end, we want the email pipeline to look something like this:

```
                               ,----> Mailbox
                              /
  Incoming message -> Exchange 
                              \
                               `----> Internal Server (processing)
```

I'm open to suggestions on other ways to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Journaling rule will do this for you. Built in to Exchange, you configure it to send to another email address, and that needs to be an address the other server accepts. You would then configure a Send Connector.

So the journaling rule might be journal@journal.example.com with a send connector for journal.example.com pointing at the other server.